# XML editing inside a Perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to us the perl -pi -e to edit the a line in a xml file. If I run the perl -pi -e command from the command line it works fine, but once I put in my script and use the system command I get the error listed below:

su: invalid option -- i

Try `su --help' for more information.

```
print "Please enter virtualhost 1 - Example - ucisha.com:";
  my $virtualhost1 = <>;
  system("ssh -t <HOST> \"sudo su - root -c perl -pi -e 's/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">  <Alias>$virtualhost1<\/Alias>/g' /tcserver/springsource-tc-server-node/UCISjvm/conf/krh.xml\"");
```

Comment: You're shelling out from perl to ssh into a remote system where you use sudo to escalate your rights and pass in a perl one-liner which edits an XML file using regular expressions? Oh my. After cowering in fear for half an hour, I'd seriously look at getting a Perl script installed on that server that took the edit requirements as command line arguments and then used a proper XML parser to make them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add quote marks around the argument you pass to `-c`.

At the moment you have `-c perl` and then `-pi` is taken as another argument to `su` not `perl`.

Comment: So try to fix the new error. As a rule of thumb, back off and build the most nested part of the program first. Then go back one level of nesting at a time, making sure you get the escaping right as you go.

Comment: I have some issues getting the code here. But now I am getting the error below:

    print "Please enter virtualhost 1 - Example - ucisha.com:";
    my $virtualhost1 = <>;
    system("ssh -t <HOST>\"sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e 's/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">  
     <Alias>$virtualhost1<\/Alias>/g' /tcserver/springsource-tc-server-node/UCISjvm/conf/krh.xml'\"");

ash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
bash: -c: line 0: `sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e 's/xmlNamespaceAware=false>/xmlNamespaceAware=false><Alias>akdljad'

Comment: You are using `'` characters unescaped in a string delimited with `'`.

Comment: How should the system string look with the escape characters?

Comment: Trying to solve 4 level deep quote nesting manually will give me a headache. The advice I gave in my first comment is the approach you should take to solve it. (That or building up the command in pieces using a library that applies suitable escaping to it).