# System() in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to call a perl script with flags from a remote server using the system command. When I issue the command my last two flags are getting ignored for some odd reason. Can some please provide me some guidance. Thanks in advance!!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Webserver?\n";
my $webserver = <STDIN>;

print "PORT?\n";
my $port = <STDIN>;

system("ssh -t <HOST> \"sudo su - root -c '/WebAppSA/apache/V2.2/install_apache/webmaster.pl -C -name:$webserver -port:$port -  cert:cert.com'\"");
```

ERROR MESSAGE
Cannot determine the unique port for the web server.
Please check your settings and try again.  Aborting...
-bash: line 1: -port:8284: command not found
-bash: line 2: -cert:cert.com: command not found

Comment: I understand that this is likely demonstration code, but please be careful — you are passing unvalidated, unescaped user-supplied input to a root shell on a remote machine.  (Your own child shell is at risk, too.)  Please look at calling `system()` with a list or indirect object and list [per the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  Alternatively, `quotemeta()` or `\Q` are better than naked interpolation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML editing inside a Perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877485/xml-editing-inside-a-perl-script)

Comment: @per the docs: `quotemeta` is for regular expresions, not for shell quoting.

Comment: @salva, yes, that's right.  It's not the appropriate tool.

Answer (score 6):

You $webserver and $port variables are ending with a new line character "\n". Use chomp function.

```
my $webserver = <STDIN>;
chomp $webserver;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

use sudo properly and then [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) for handling the ssh connection:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->system(sudo => '/WebAppSA/apache/V2.2/install_apache/webmaster.pl',
                     '-C', "-name:$webserver", "-port:$port", '-cert:cert.com');
```

Net::OpenSSH will take care of properly quoting everything.