# system(perl -pi -e) for XML editing

Tags: xml, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML editing inside a Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877485/xml-editing-inside-a-perl-script)

Can someone please help me. I am about to go nuts looking at this one line. I am trying to user the perl -pi -e to edit a XML file.

```
 system("ssh -t <HOST> \"sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e 's/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\">/xmlNamespaceAware=\"false\"><Alias>$virtualhost1<\/Alias>/g' /home/harrikr/Scripts/TcServerScripts/data.xml'\"");
```

This will not work I have tried all types of combinations.

Comment: "_I am trying to user the perl -pi -e to edit a XML file._" Ok, but what's the goal by editing that file? Do you get any error?

Comment: define "will not work". And please tell me the problem is that the server you're trying to access has some semblance of sane security and you can't sudo to root like that.

Comment: I get error messages complaining about the operators.
Bareword found where operator expected at Untitled.pl line 7, near ""ssh -t harrikr\@<HOST> \"sudo su - root -c perl -pi -e 's{xmlNamespaceAware="false"
String found where operator expected at Untitled.pl line 7, near "false">}{xmlNamespaceAware=""
Bareword found where operator expected at Untitled.pl line 7, near "">}{xmlNamespaceAware="false"
(Missing operator before false?)

Comment: @user1272415, Are you sure sudo and su are both needed? Seems redundant to call su if you can call sudo.

Answer (score 3):

You asked this question already, and the answer was that you have the quoting all mixed up. Here's what you have:

```
"ssh -t <HOST> \"sudo su - root -c 'perl -pi -e '...' ...'\""
```

Let's take the bits inside the single quotes and replace them with nonsense:

```
"ssh -t <HOST> \"sudo su - root -c 'AAA'...'BBB'\""
```

It looks to me like `perl` isn't going to get the program you think it's getting because you're prematurely closing off the quotes. Instead of trying to specify everything in one string, build it up so the escaping is easier to grok:

```
my $perl = q(perl -pi -e \\'...\\');
my $command = qq(sudo su - root -c '$perl');
```

Why are you trying to to do this in a big system call? I now about situations from my own work  where this sort of thing was necessary, but I also know that I solved it with [Net::SSH::Perl::ProxiedIPC](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl%3a%3aProxiedIPC). It handles all of these goofy details.

And, as the previous answer to your same question points out, those `sudo` and `su` invocations are really scary.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed the last answer but this was very helpful. I think Net::SSH::Perl::ProxiedIPC will be very helpful with that I have to accomplish. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Build it from the inside out.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $host         = 'HOST';
my $path_to_xml  = '/home/harrikr/Scripts/TcServerScripts/data.xml';
my $virtualhost1 = 'VIRTUALHOST1';

my $perl_prog = <<'__EOI__';
    BEGIN { my $vh = shift(@ARGV); }
    s/xmlNamespaceAware="false">\K/<Alias>\Q$vh\E</Alias>/g;
__EOI__

my $perl_cmd = sprintf q{perl -i -pe%s %s %s},
   shell_quote($perl_prog),
   shell_quote($virtualhost1),
   shell_quote($path_to_xml);

my $su_cmd = sprintf q{sudo su - -c%s},
    shell_quote($perl_cmd);

my $ssh_cmd = sprintf q{ssh -t %s %s},
   shell_quote($host),
   shell_quote($su_cmd);

system($ssh_cmd);
```

You may notice I shortened your Perl program through the use of the \K regex atom. That requires 5.10, so feel free to revert that change.

---

Becoming root appears to be unnecessary. Since the file being edited appears to belong to `harrikr` why not simply ssh as that person? I think that also means that `-t` becomes unnecessary.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $host         = 'harrikr@HOST';
my $path_to_xml  = '/home/harrikr/Scripts/TcServerScripts/data.xml';
my $virtualhost1 = 'VIRTUALHOST1';

my $perl_prog = <<'__EOI__';
    BEGIN { my $vh = shift(@ARGV); }
    s/xmlNamespaceAware="false">\K/<Alias>\Q$vh\E</Alias>/g;
__EOI__

my $perl_cmd = sprintf q{perl -i -pe%s %s %s},
   shell_quote($perl_prog),
   shell_quote($virtualhost1),
   shell_quote($path_to_xml);

my $ssh_cmd = sprintf q{ssh %s %s},
   shell_quote($host),
   shell_quote($perl_cmd);

system($ssh_cmd);
```

Comment: The file owned by root but the test case file is owned by harrikr

Comment: @user1272415, Net::SSH::Perl::ProxiedIPC has three limitations that affect you. As far as I can tell, ProxiedIPC doesn't provide a means for you to do the su and/or sudo (without shelling out, which brings you right back to the original problem), ProxiedIPC doesn't allow you to pass command line options to Perl, and ProxiedIPC doesn't allow you to pass arguments to the Perl script.

Comment: Ike I took that code and entered my names and it ssh to the remote server but did not modify the data.xml. I dont see where you define shell_quote($host) ..$host

Comment: If you mean "I dont see where you define shell_quote", then the answer is "use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );". Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: That is what I meant sorry .. I have been working through this for a week and I am new to perl .. Really good at BASH scripting but I cant get this one last piece to work. Even with your suggestions I can get the data to write to the data.xml file. The sudo seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: In BASH I could put some `` around the string and everything would work perfectly.. But I am modifying an existing perl script. I am about to pull my hair out over this!!!

Comment: @user1272415, No, placing what you have in `system("...")` (in Perl) into `` (in bash) would not work. The shell command is incorrectly built no matter which program launches it.

Comment: So basically there is no solution for me?

Comment: @user1272415, Try changing `q{perl -i -pe%s %s %s}` to `q{echo %s %s %s}` for debugging.

Comment: @user1272415, Not at all. You didn't say what didn't work, so there's no much for us to do but wildly speculate as to your problem, and that's a waste of time.

Comment: Now I get this message:
 BEGIN { my $vh = shift(@ARGV); }
    s/xmlNamespaceAware="false">\K/<Alias>\Q$vh\E</Alias>/g;
 VIRTUALHOST1 /home/harrikr/Scripts/TcServerScripts/data.xml